# Process XML output from API

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am getting an XML return from an Ebay API call. This is actually an Ebay category list of collections. But the problem is, I can't access its collection from XML output. I have attached two pictures - the first one showing debug of XML value returning variable, and the second one showing "InnerList". My main goal is prepare this XML data to store on my database, so I need a clean list of values from XML data. Any ideas?

[image: Picture One]

[image: Picture Two]

Comment: `categories.InnerList` or `categories.List` is what you need to use to get the categories information.

Comment: Isn't it the `List` property that you need?

Comment: Have nothing to do with XML, you get already serialized collection of some types - where you can access/remove data through their properties

Comment: Sounds good. Any idea how to access those collection then? @Fabio

Comment: Show data you get and show data you need for database, then if you will not be able to transform it from one to another - ask for the problem you face with

Comment: ibb.co/mwK1W5 this is the inside one of collection. I want only "CategoryName" and "CategoryID" to save into my database @Fabio

Answer (score 1):

You could deserialize your xml into your own class/object - Then it might be easier to work with. All i do is put xml tags to a class and i can deserialize it. See the class and method below:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText)
{
    try
    {
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

[XmlElement("adress")]
public class Adress
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("street_address")]
    public string street_address { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("postal_code")]
    public string postal_code { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public main()
{
     Adress myAdress = Deserialize<Adress>(XMLstring);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Ebay SDK. Please try code below to process return values.

```
foreach (CategoryTypeCollection item in categories)
                    {
                        item.ItemAt(0).CategoryID = "This is how you access the properties of he returned result";
                        // THE XML is already parsed for you via SDK, so you don't have to parse it... 
                        // since i wrote foreach loop here, always access itemAt 0th index posiiton 
                    }
```